# Powershell convertfrom -Json error after converting to base64

Tags: arrays, powershell, base64

I am trying to do the below in powershell and getting an error unable to figure out reason.

Below works fine

```
$config = @"
{
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\result20171120"
}
"@

$abc = ConvertFrom-Json $testconfig
```

But when I pass in base64 of the above(as script which I use expects base64)

```
$config = "QCINCnsNCgkiQ29tbW9uLkJpbkRpciI6ICJHOlxyZXN1bHQiLA0KCSJJbmZyYXN0cnVjdHVyZS5XZWJSb290IjogIkc6XHJlc3VsdDIwMTcxMTIwIg0KfQ0KIkA="
$decodedConfig = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($config))
$abc = ConvertFrom-Json $decodedConfig
```

I get below error upon running the convert command

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:1 char:8
+ $abc = ConvertFrom-Json $decodedConfig
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], 
ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Comment: Where the `$testconfig` (in the former example) and the `$config` (in the later one) come from?  Please [edit] the question to match a [mcve] rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two things
1) String decoded from base64 contains @" and "@  - as part of string, not qualifier - so

`$decodedString` is:

```
@"
{
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\result20171120"
} 
"@
```

While `$config` is:

```
{
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\result20171120"
}
```

Below would work in Your case (although there must be better way to do it)

```
$abc = ConvertFrom-Json 
($decodedConfig($decodedConfig.Replace('@"','')).replace('"@',''))
```

2) You need to mask `\` in .Json files , so effectively You need to use `\\` so in fact it Your Json should look like this:

```
@"
{
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\\result20171120"
} 
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet should work as expected for the given `$config`:

```
$config = "QCINCnsNCgkiQ29tbW9uLkJpbkRpciI6ICJHOlxyZXN1bHQiLA0KCSJJbmZyYXN0cnVjdHVyZS5XZWJSb290IjogIkc6XHJlc3VsdDIwMTcxMTIwIg0KfQ0KIkA="
$decodedConfig = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($config))
$abc = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $(
    Invoke-Expression -Command $decodedConfig.Replace('\', '\\')
    )
```

Comment: Is there someway I can do to @"
{
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\result20171120"
}
"@, rather than changing the decodedConfig or abc code as these code is part of script which I am unable to change

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the issue, decoding the below {
    "Common.BinDir": "G:\\result",
    "Infrastructure.WebRoot": "G:\\result20171120"
}
helped